# Spinner text not showing the default value, nor the selected value

Tags: java, android, text, spinner

The options for the spinner are only visible when I hit the spinner arrow. However, the default text and the selected text fail to show.

This is the xml for the spinner :

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColor = "#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/roleNameTag"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/insertPass" />
```

This is the java code :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_page);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,R.id.spinner1); */


    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.atco_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner.setSelection(0,true); //set the default value
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)

    //here however, we just set the spinner value to the one selected
    String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(text);
    spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
    }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
    spinner.setSelection(0,true); //set the default value
}
}
```

And this is what I have tried :

[Spinner control not showing the selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841568/spinner-control-not-showing-the-selected-text)

[Android: setSelection having no effect on Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484528/android-setselection-having-no-effect-on-spinner)

These were the only relevant ones I found.

I set the text color to black.
Set the default value , both right after setAdapter in onCreate and in the onNothingSelected methods , still nothing.
Included the "true" boolean in the setSelection function.

Android API v21

Help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, atco_array);
```

You not added any data into `adapter` to show in Spinner, so that is occurs.
Set Data into `adapter` before call `setSelection(0,true)`, it might be help you.

Comment: R.array.atco_array is where it gets its values. They are stored in a file in the values folder. And I said that the values are visible when I click the arrow to select them, but do not show in the tab itself

Comment: Not working, because it needs a CharSequence and it is getting a String. I think the problem is with "this" in your line.